# How to accelerate the speed with multiple input to calcution the length of upload images?

Tags: javascript, html

code:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="calcLength" />

document.getElementById('calcLength').onchange = function(){
    alert(this.files.length)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zq1fet71/16/

test env :
  pc: windows7 chrome58.0; macOS10.12 chrome58.0
  mobile: iphone6 ios10.3 safari; iphone6s ios10.3 safari

step:
1: to click the button with upload; then it will open a system window
2: to choice twenty or thirty images. everyone of these images is panorama photo. i take panorama photos with iphone6

expect:
to click the finish button in system window. then i got a response(alert) without delay in pc environment. i also want there is no delay in mobile

actual:
**click the finish button in mobile system window, i got a delay about two to three seconds**

Comment: What mobile in particular? I'd rather guess that when selecting the file it tries to load it into memory or some stuff like that, and that slows down the phone.

Comment: I said *memory* not processor, but what else could affect performance like that? Also it's very hard to reproduce your problem. Please specify what device model, os version and browser you are using, which files you are selecting how from where, and what exactly "it is too slow" means.